# Swift splitting "abc1.23.456.7890xyz" into "abc", "1", "23", "456", "7890" and "xyz"

Tags: regex, macos, swift2, nsregularexpression

In Swift on OS X I am trying to chop up the string "abc1.23.456.7890xyz" into these strings:

```
"abc"
"1"
"23"
"456"
"7890"
"xyz"
```

but when I run the following code I get the following:

```
=> "abc1.23.456.7890xyz"
(0,3) -> "abc"
(3,1) -> "1"
(12,4) -> "7890"
(16,3) -> "xyz"
```

which means that the application correctly found "abc", the first token "1", but then the next token found is "7890" (missing out "23" and "456") followed by "xyz".

Can anyone see how the code can be changed to find ALL of the strings (including "23" and "456")?

Many thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation
import XCTest

public
class StackOverflowTest: XCTestCase {
    public
    func testRegex() {
        do {
            let patternString = "([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)(?:\\.([0-9]+))*([^0-9]*)"
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: patternString, options: [])

            let string = "abc1.23.456.7890xyz"
            print("=> \"\(string)\"")

            let range = NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count)
            regex.enumerateMatchesInString(string, options: [], range: range) {
                (textCheckingResult, _, _) in
                if let textCheckingResult = textCheckingResult {
                    for nsRangeIndex in 1 ..< textCheckingResult.numberOfRanges {
                        let nsRange = textCheckingResult.rangeAtIndex(nsRangeIndex)
                        let location = nsRange.location
                        if location < Int.max {
                            let startIndex = string.startIndex.advancedBy(location)
                            let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(nsRange.length)
                            let value = string[startIndex ..< endIndex]
                            print("\(nsRange) -> \"\(value)\"")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about your regex pattern. You want to find a series of contiguous letters or digits. Try this pattern instead:

```
let patternString = "([a-zA-Z]+|\\d+)"
```

Comment: This is certainly a massive improvement.  But it is not quite there for me because although the string "abc1.23.456.7890xyz" is splitting correctly into "abc", "1", "23", "456", "7890" and "xyz", the string "1.23.456.7890xyz" should return "", "1", "23", "456", "7890" and "xyz", but is returning "1", "23", "456", "7890" and "xyz". Similarly the string "1.23.456.7890" should return "", "1", "23", "456", "7890" and "", but is returning "1", "23", "456" and "7890". How can I force the start and end strings to always appear even if they are empty?

Comment: Have you considered adding these empty elements to the start and end of your match list, independent of the regex? These empty elements weren't in your original question

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  I now see that the solution involves 2 separate regular expressions: one for the outer section "([^0-9]*)([0-9\\.]+)([^0-9]*)" then another for the inner section "([^0-9.]+|\\d+)".  In the example of "abc1.23.456.7890xyz" the outer section gives us "abc", "1.23.456.7890" and "xyz".  Then the inner section can be applied to just "1.23.456.7890" to give the strings "1", "23", "456" and "7890".

Answer (score 0):

alternative 'Swifty' way

```
let str = "abc1.23.456.7890xyz"
let chars = str.characters.map{ $0 }

enum CharType {
    case Number
    case Alpha
    init(c: Character) {
        self = .Alpha
        if isNumber(c) {
            self = .Number
        }
    }
    func isNumber(c: Character)->Bool {
        return "1234567890".characters.map{ $0 }.contains(c)
    }    
}

var tmp = ""
tmp.append(chars[0])
var type = CharType(c: chars[0])

for i in 1..<chars.count {
    let c = CharType(c: chars[i])

    if c != type {
        tmp.append(Character("."))
    }
    tmp.append(chars[i])
    type = c
}
tmp.characters.split(".", maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false).map(String.init)
// ["abc", "1", "23", "456", "7890", "xyz"]
```